# PHP abstract class fatal error

Tags: php, abstract-class

I got a problem with abstract class. Currently i use abstract class runnable to determine what my API need to work.

```
abstract class runnable {
    abstract protected function __setConfig();
    abstract public function __run(api $api);
    
    public function run(api $api){
        $this->__setConfig();
        $this->__run($api);
    }
}
```

I haven't got problem with this, but when i miss one method i got this fatal error:

`Fatal error: Class MyClass contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (runnable::__setConfig)`

I would like know how i can test if runnable's conditions are met before instanciate MyClass, i have tried with [ReflectionClass::isInstantiable](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/reflectionclass.isinstantiable.php) but i get again this error...

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($appName);
if($reflectionClass->IsInstantiable()) {
  // OK
} else {
  // Cutom error
}
```

How i can make it properly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're treading a dangerous path prefixing your methods with `__` - PHP reserves method names beginning with two underscores

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as soon you extend your class to an abstract it will throw an error if it doesn't contain's the methods ( even before initiate the class ).

You can't do it with reflection because is for reflection alone as the name states.

You can try to hack it with [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) , it should be the only way to do what you want.

But in the end i don't really know why you should need to do this, why don't you just extend it to a normal class instead of a abstract one? ( if you don't really care about it )

Answer (score 0):

For this case you might create an Interface something like that:

```
interface runnableInterface {
   public function run(api $api);
   public function setConfig();
}

abstract class runnableAbstract implement runnableInterface {
    public function run(api $api){
        $this->setConfig();
        $this->run($api);
    }
}

class runnable extends runnableAbstract implement runnableInterface {
     public function setConfig() {
         // do something here
     };
     public function run(api $api){
        $this->setConfig();
        $this->run($api);
     }
}
```

Also you can read [Object Interfaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php#language.oop5.interfaces) and [Class Abstraction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)